# Identify a region given its restraint

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I am in a calc 3 class and we are currently working on absolute minimums and maximums of extremas of functions of two variables. First I will post an image of a HW question that I am having a bit of trouble with:
[image]

I am just not sure how to draw the graph for the region given the information `D={(x,y) | 0 <= y <= x <= 4}`
How should I look at the constraints given for this region to be able to draw out its graph? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region $D$ is the intersection of three regions:

- $0 \le y$ is the upper half plane (everything above and including the $x$-axis)
- $y \le x$ is the region below and including the line $y = x$
- $x \le 4$ is everything to the left of and including the vertical line $x = 4$

Comment: Thanks! The y≤x is what was giving me rough time. Now that you pointed it out I see how it can be seen as y=x, but then y≤x (under the y=x line). Thanks again!